# Convert xml to csv in Python

Tags: python, xml, csv

I have the following XML structure and I am trying to convert it into a csv in python:

```
<FIXML><Batch>
<PosRpt RptID="34868232064" ReqID="C905EOD20160427" SetSesID="EOD" MtchStat="0" PriSetPx="326.6" SetPx="328.3" SetPxTyp="1" SettlCcy="USD" ReqTyp="1" MsgEvtSrc="REG" BizDt="2016-04-27" SettlDt="2016-07-14" SettlCurrFxRt="1"><Pty ID="CME" R="21"></Pty><Pty ID="905" R="4"></Pty><Pty ID="CBT" R="22"></Pty><Pty ID="905" R="38"><Sub ID="1" Typ="26"/></Pty><Pty ID="905" R="1"></Pty><Instrmt ID="06" Desc="SOYBEAN MEAL FUTURES" CFI="FCAPSO" SecTyp="FUT" Src="H" MMY="201607" MatDt="2016-07-14" Mult="100" Exch="CBT" UOM="tn" UOMQty="100" PxUOM="TON" PxUOMQty="1" ValMeth="FUT" Fctr="1" PxQteCcy="USD" FnlSettlCcy="USD"></Instrmt><Qty Long="2038" Short="1354" Typ="ETR"/><Qty Long="1289" Short="1436" Typ="ALC"/><Qty Long="0" Short="10" Typ="TRF"/><Qty Long="4122" Short="8098" Typ="SOD"/><Qty Long="3957" Short="7406" Typ="FIN"/><Qty Long="937" Short="6325" Typ="IES"/><Qty Long="35" Short="55" Typ="IAS"/><Amt Typ="SMTM" Amt="-675920" Ccy="USD"/><Amt Typ="TVAR" Amt="-325070.33" Ccy="USD"/><Amt Typ="FMTM" Amt="-1000990.33" Ccy="USD"/></PosRpt>
<TrdCaptRpt RptID="21195360680" TrdTyp="0" TrdSubTyp="5" ExecID="85271320160426220810TN0002521" TrdDt="2016-04-27" BizDt="2016-04-27" MLegRptTyp="1" MtchStat="0" MsgEvtSrc="REG" TrdID="106695" LastQty="1" LastPx="323.5" TxnTm="2016-04-27T01:10:25-05:00" SettlCcy="USD" SettlDt="2016-07-14" PxSubTyp="1" VenueTyp="E" VenuTyp="E" OfstInst="0"><Instrmt ID="06" Desc="SOYBEAN MEAL FUTURES" CFI="FCAPSO" SecTyp="FUT" MMY="201607" MatDt="2016-07-14" Mult="100" Exch="CBT" UOM="tn" UOMQty="100" PxUOM="TON" PxUOMQty="1" ValMeth="FUT" Fctr="1" PxQteCcy="USD"></Instrmt><Amt Typ="TVAR" Amt="480" Ccy="USD"/><RptSide Side="1" ClOrdID="25245816" CustCpcty="4" OrdTyp="M" SesID="EOD" SesSub="E" AllocInd="1" AgrsrInd="Y"><Pty ID="CME" R="21"></Pty><Pty ID="905" R="4"></Pty><Pty ID="CBT" R="22"></Pty><Pty ID="905" R="1"></Pty><Pty ID="434GU400" R="24"><Sub ID="1" Typ="26"/></Pty><Pty ID="4QOL" R="12"></Pty><Pty ID="685" R="17"></Pty><Pty ID="4QOL" R="37"></Pty><Pty ID="905" R="38"><Sub ID="1" Typ="26"/></Pty><Pty ID="905" R="7"></Pty><RegTrdID ID="FECC1544943BFEC0302D5F8342" Src="1010000023" Typ="0" Evnt="2"/></RptSide></TrdCaptRpt>
<TrdCaptRpt RptID="21196531008" TrdTyp="0" TrdSubTyp="5" ExecID="88421020160427065733TN0007200" TrdDt="2016-04-27" BizDt="2016-04-27" MLegRptTyp="1" MtchStat="0" MsgEvtSrc="REG" TrdID="115357" LastQty="2" LastPx="325.7" TxnTm="2016-04-27T07:00:12-05:00" SettlCcy="USD" SettlDt="2016-07-14" PxSubTyp="1" VenueTyp="E" VenuTyp="E" OfstInst="0"><Instrmt ID="06" Desc="SOYBEAN MEAL FUTURES" CFI="FCAPSO" SecTyp="FUT" MMY="201607" MatDt="2016-07-14" Mult="100" Exch="CBT" UOM="tn" UOMQty="100" PxUOM="TON" PxUOMQty="1" ValMeth="FUT" Fctr="1" PxQteCcy="USD"></Instrmt><Amt Typ="TVAR" Amt="-520" Ccy="USD"/><RptSide Side="2" ClOrdID="25246712" CustCpcty="4" OrdTyp="M" SesID="EOD" SesSub="E" AllocInd="1" AgrsrInd="Y"><Pty ID="CME" R="21"></Pty><Pty ID="905" R="4"></Pty><Pty ID="CBT" R="22"></Pty><Pty ID="905" R="1"></Pty><Pty ID="434GU400" R="24"><Sub ID="1" Typ="26"/></Pty><Pty ID="4QOL" R="12"></Pty><Pty ID="685" R="17"></Pty><Pty ID="4QOL" R="37"></Pty><Pty ID="905" R="38"><Sub ID="1" Typ="26"/></Pty><Pty ID="905" R="7"></Pty><RegTrdID ID="FECC1544943BFEC0302D64A564" Src="1010000023" Typ="0" Evnt="2"/></RptSide></TrdCaptRpt>
<PosRpt RptID="34868266266" ReqID="C905EOD20160427" SetSesID="EOD" MtchStat="0" PriSetPx="136" SetPx="136" SetPxTyp="1" SettlCcy="USD" ReqTyp="1" MsgEvtSrc="REG" BizDt="2016-04-27" SettlDt="2016-12-28" SettlCurrFxRt="1"><Pty ID="CME" R="21"></Pty><Pty ID="905" R="4"></Pty><Pty ID="CBT" R="22"></Pty><Pty ID="99106105" R="38"><Sub ID="2" Typ="26"/></Pty><Pty ID="905" R="1"></Pty><Instrmt ID="UFU" Desc="UAN FOB NOLA SWAP" CFI="FCACSO" SecTyp="FUT" Src="H" MMY="201612" MatDt="2016-12-28" Mult="100" Exch="CBT" UOM="tn" UOMQty="100" PxUOM="TON" PxUOMQty="1" ValMeth="FUT" Fctr="1" PxQteCcy="USD" FnlSettlCcy="USD"></Instrmt><Qty Long="30" Short="0" Typ="SOD"/><Qty Long="30" Short="0" Typ="FIN"/><Qty Long="30" Short="0" Typ="IES"/><Amt Typ="SMTM" Amt="0" Ccy="USD"/><Amt Typ="TVAR" Amt="0" Ccy="USD"/><Amt Typ="FMTM" Amt="0" Ccy="USD"/><RegTrdID ID="PSC152CEF79387P0203D81FA" Src="1010000023" Typ="0" Evnt="2"/></PosRpt>
<PosRpt RptID="34868372999" ReqID="C905EOD20160427" SetSesID="EOD" MtchStat="0" PriSetPx="675.25" SetPx="669.25" SetPxTyp="1" SettlCcy="USD" ReqTyp="1" MsgEvtSrc="REG" BizDt="2016-04-27" SettlDt="2016-06-30" SettlCurrFxRt="1"><Pty ID="CME" R="21"></Pty><Pty ID="905" R="4"></Pty><Pty ID="CME" R="22"></Pty><Pty ID="98812736" R="38"><Sub ID="2" Typ="26"/></Pty><Pty ID="905" R="1"></Pty><Instrmt ID="CPC" Desc="MALAYSIAN CRUDE PALM OIL CAL S" CFI="FCACSO" SecTyp="FUT" Src="H" MMY="201606" MatDt="2016-06-30" Mult="25" Exch="CME" UOMQty="25" PxUOM="MTONS" PxUOMQty="1" ValMeth="FUT" Fctr="1" PxQteCcy="USD" FnlSettlCcy="USD"></Instrmt><Qty Long="0" Short="200" Typ="SOD"/><Qty Long="0" Short="200" Typ="FIN"/><Qty Long="0" Short="200" Typ="IES"/><Amt Typ="SMTM" Amt="30000" Ccy="USD"/><Amt Typ="TVAR" Amt="0" Ccy="USD"/><Amt Typ="FMTM" Amt="30000" Ccy="USD"/><RegTrdID ID="PSC154373D5298P0302DFC70" Src="1010000023" Typ="0" Evnt="2"/></PosRpt>
<PosRpt RptID="34868373000" ReqID="C905EOD20160427" SetSesID="EOD" MtchStat="0" PriSetPx="665.75" SetPx="661.5" SetPxTyp="1" SettlCcy="USD" ReqTyp="1" MsgEvtSrc="REG" BizDt="2016-04-27" SettlDt="2016-11-30" SettlCurrFxRt="1"><Pty ID="CME" R="21"></Pty><Pty ID="905" R="4"></Pty><Pty ID="CME" R="22"></Pty><Pty ID="98812736" R="38"><Sub ID="2" Typ="26"/></Pty><Pty ID="905" R="1"></Pty><Instrmt ID="CPC" Desc="MALAYSIAN CRUDE PALM OIL CAL S" CFI="FCACSO" SecTyp="FUT" Src="H" MMY="201611" MatDt="2016-11-30" Mult="25" Exch="CME" UOMQty="25" PxUOM="MTONS" PxUOMQty="1" ValMeth="FUT" Fctr="1" PxQteCcy="USD" FnlSettlCcy="USD"></Instrmt><Qty Long="0" Short="400" Typ="SOD"/><Qty Long="0" Short="400" Typ="FIN"/><Qty Long="0" Short="400" Typ="IES"/><Amt Typ="SMTM" Amt="42500" Ccy="USD"/><Amt Typ="TVAR" Amt="0" Ccy="USD"/><Amt Typ="FMTM" Amt="42500" Ccy="USD"/><RegTrdID ID="PSC1540E0A7EA6P0302DFB8E" Src="1010000023" Typ="0" Evnt="2"/></PosRpt>
<TrdCaptRpt RptID="21202575211" TrdTyp="0" TrdDt="2016-04-27" BizDt="2016-04-27" MLegRptTyp="2" MtchStat="1" MsgEvtSrc="REG" TrdID="000991" LastQty="100" LastPx="0.31" TxnTm="2016-04-27T12:33:54-05:00" SettlCcy="USD" SettlDt="2016-08-03" OrigTrdID="15457C3D779LEB0202D1BC6" PxSubTyp="1" VenueTyp="P" VenuTyp="P"><Instrmt ID="DA" Desc="CLASS III MILK OPTIONS" CFI="OCAXPS" SecTyp="OOF" MMY="201607" MatDt="2016-08-03" StrkPx="13.75" Mult="2000" Exch="CME" UOM="lbs" UOMQty="200000" PxUOM="LBS" PxUOMQty="100" PutCall="1" ValMeth="EQTY" Fctr="1" PxQteCcy="USD"></Instrmt><Undly CFI="FCACSO" Desc="CLASS III MILK FUTURES" ID="DA" Src="H" MMY="201607" SecTyp="FUT" Exch="CME"></Undly><Amt Typ="PREM" Amt="62000" Ccy="USD"/><RptSide Side="2" ClOrdID="660" CustCpcty="4" OrdTyp="L" SesID="EOD" SesSub="P" TmBkt="V" AllocInd="1" AgrsrInd="Y"><Pty ID="CME" R="21"></Pty><Pty ID="905" R="4"></Pty><Pty ID="CME" R="22"></Pty><Pty ID="905" R="1"></Pty><Pty ID="77040322" R="24"><Sub ID="1" Typ="26"/></Pty><Pty ID="BKF" R="12"></Pty><Pty ID="826" R="17"></Pty><Pty ID="BLT" R="37"></Pty><Pty ID="905" R="38"><Sub ID="1" Typ="26"/></Pty><Pty ID="905" R="7"></Pty><RegTrdID ID="FECC15457C3D779LEB0202D1BC8" Src="1010000023" Typ="0" Evnt="2"/></RptSide></TrdCaptRpt>
<TrdCaptRpt RptID="21206412158" TrdTyp="0" TrdSubTyp="5" TrdDt="2016-04-27" BizDt="2016-04-27" MLegRptTyp="1" MtchStat="1" MsgEvtSrc="REG" TrdID="124710" LastQty="5" LastPx="0.13" SettlCcy="USD" SettlDt="2016-08-31" PxSubTyp="1" VenueTyp="P" VenuTyp="P" OfstInst="0"><Instrmt ID="DA" Desc="CLASS III MILK OPTIONS" CFI="OPAXPS" SecTyp="OOF" MMY="201608" MatDt="2016-08-31" StrkPx="13" Mult="2000" Exch="CME" UOM="lbs" UOMQty="200000" PxUOM="LBS" PxUOMQty="100" PutCall="0" ValMeth="EQTY" Fctr="1" PxQteCcy="USD"></Instrmt><Undly CFI="FCACSO" Desc="CLASS III MILK FUTURES" ID="DA" Src="H" MMY="201608" SecTyp="FUT" Exch="CME"></Undly><Amt Typ="PREM" Amt="1300" Ccy="USD" SettlDt="2016-04-27"/><RptSide Side="2" ClOrdID="726" CustCpcty="4" OrdTyp="L" SesID="EOD" SesSub="P" TmBkt="M" AllocInd="1" AgrsrInd="Y"><Pty ID="CME" R="21"></Pty><Pty ID="905" R="4"></Pty><Pty ID="CME" R="22"></Pty><Pty ID="905" R="1"></Pty><Pty ID="7704038A" R="24"><Sub ID="1" Typ="26"/></Pty><Pty ID="GRTY" R="12"></Pty><Pty ID="888" R="17"></Pty><Pty ID="GRTY" R="37"></Pty><Pty ID="905" R="38"><Sub ID="1" Typ="26"/></Pty><Pty ID="905" R="7"></Pty><RegTrdID ID="FECC1544943BFEC0302D9028AE" Src="1010000023" Typ="0" Evnt="2"/></RptSide></TrdCaptRpt>
</Batch></FIXML>
```

And I am trying to convert this into a csv file. I have tried it with the following code but I can;t get the right output:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
import csv

my_list = []

with open('/Users/testuser/Desktop/CMEREG1.XML', 'rt') as f:
    tree = ElementTree.parse(f)

for node in tree.iter('TrdCaptRpt'):
    RptID = node.attrib.get('RptID')
    TrdTyp = node.attrib.get('TrdTyp')
    TrdSubTyp = node.attrib.get('TrdSubTyp')
    TrdDt = node.attrib.get('TrdDt')
    BizDt = node.attrib.get('BizDt')
    MLegRptTyp = node.attrib.get('MLegRptTyp')
    MtchStat = node.attrib.get('MtchStat')
    MsgEvtSrc = node.attrib.get('MsgEvtSrc')
    TrdID = node.attrib.get('TrdID')
    LastQty = node.attrib.get('LastQty')
    LastPx = node.attrib.get('LastPx')
    TxnTm = node.attrib.get('TxnTm')
    SettlCcy = node.attrib.get('SettlCcy')
    SettlDt = node.attrib.get('SettlDt')
    PxSubTyp = node.attrib.get('PxSubTyp')
    VenueTyp = node.attrib.get('VenueTyp')
    VenuTyp = node.attrib.get('VenuTyp')
    OfstInst = node.attrib.get('OfstInst')

    my_list.append[node.attrib.get('RptID')]

    print RptID, TrdTyp, TrdSubTyp, TrdDt, BizDt, MLegRptTyp, MtchStat, MsgEvtSrc, TrdID, LastQty, LastPx, TxnTm, SettlCcy, SettlDt, PxSubTyp, VenueTyp, VenuTyp, OfstInst

with open('/Users/anantsangar/Desktop/output.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    spamwriter.writerow(my_list)
```

I can't get every tag into the csv. Is there a easy way to export this to a CSV ?

Thank you

Comment: What is expected output? It seems, you care only about TrdCapRpt elements, do you?

Comment: well the format of this piece of xml is a little bit ugly..and yes, since there are several types of elements, despite that data were kept in attributes, do you only care this TrdCaptRpt, sounds like some trade capital report?

Comment: @JanVlcinsky yes TrdCapRpt but also PosRpt and Amt.

Comment: man, TrdCapRpt / PosRpt / Amt are in different format, column count, level, you could have a better look of your xml by format it first, import xml.dom.minidom; xml_root = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(str_xml); print xml_root.toprettyxml(), wheter you'd put them in one file or seperate one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Use `csv.DictWriter`, get values from `node.attrib` dictionary

Your elements named `TrdCapRpt` have attributes, if you have such node, its attribute `node.attrib`
holds a dictionary with key/value for each attribute.

`csv.DictWriter` allows writing data taken from dictionary.

First some imports (I always use `lxml` as it is very fast and provides extra features):

```
from lxml import etree
import csv
```

Configure file names and fields to use in each record:

```
xml_fname = "data.xml"
csv_fname = "data.csv"

fields = [
    "RptID", "TrdTyp", "TrdSubTyp", "ExecID", "TrdDt", "BizDt", "MLegRptTyp",
    "MtchStat" "MsgEvtSrc", "TrdID", "LastQty", "LastPx", "TxnTm", "SettlCcy",
    "SettlDt", "PxSubTyp", "VenueTyp", "VenuTyp", "OfstInst"]
```

Read the XML:

```
xml = etree.parse(xml_fname)
```

Iterate over elements "TrdCapRpt", write attribute values to CSV file:

```
with open(csv_fname, "w") as f:

    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fields, delimiter=";", extrasaction="ignore")
    writer.writeheader()
    for node in xml.iter("TrdCaptRpt"):
        writer.writerow(node.attrib)
```

If you prefer using stdlib `xml.etree.ElementTree`, you shall manage easily as you do now, because the `node.attrib` is present there too.

## Reading from multiple element names

In your comments, you noted, that you want to export attributes from more
element names.  This is also possible. To do this, I will modify the example to
use `xpath` (which will probably work only with `lxml`) and add extra column
`"elm_name"` to track, from which element is the record created:

```
fields = [
    "elm_name",

    "RptID", "TrdTyp", "TrdSubTyp", "ExecID", "TrdDt", "BizDt", "MLegRptTyp",
    "MtchStat" "MsgEvtSrc", "TrdID", "LastQty", "LastPx", "TxnTm", "SettlCcy",
    "SettlDt", "PxSubTyp", "VenueTyp", "VenuTyp", "OfstInst",

    "Typ", "Amt", "Ccy"
]

xml = etree.parse(xml_fname)

with open(csv_fname, "w") as f:

    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fields, delimiter=";", extrasaction="ignore")
    writer.writeheader()
    for node in xml.xpath("//*[self::TrdCaptRpt or self::PosRpt or self::Amt]"):
        atts = node.attrib
        atts["elm_name"] = node.tag
        writer.writerow(node.attrib)
```

The modifications are:

- `fields` got extra `"elm_name"` field and fields from other elements (feel free to remove those you are not interested at).
- iterate over elements using `xml.xpath`. The XPath expression is more complex so I am not sure, if stdlib ElementTree supports that.
- before writing the record, I add name of the element into `atts` dictionary to provide name of the element.

Warning: the element `Amt` is nested inside `PosRpt` and this tree structure
is not possible to support in CSV. The records are written, but do not hold
information about where they come from (apart from following the record for
parent element).

Comment: @Tezirg Added solution for reading from multiple element names.

Comment: this is so helpful. One last thing how would I get the header in the csv file ? So i want to have all the tag as headers and then the data

Comment: @AnantSangar Added one line with `writer.writeheader()`. The `csv.DictWriter` is really nicely designed, isn't it?.

Answer (score 0):

You should first push each line with all your tags into a list.

```
for node in tree.iter('TrdCaptRpt'):

    .....

    my_list.push([RptID, TrdTyp, TrdSubTyp, TrdDt, BizDt, 
                  MLegRptTyp, MtchStat, MsgEvtSrc, TrdID, 
                  LastQty, LastPx, TxnTm, SettlCcy, SettlDt, 
                  PxSubTyp, VenueTyp, VenuTyp, OfstInst])
```

Then write each line to file :

```
with open('/Users/anantsangar/Desktop/output.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
for row in my_list:
    spamwriter.writerow(row)
```